# When is Quantum State Teleportation useful?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-teleportation

I've been working through the Brilliant Course on [Quantum Computing](https://brilliant.org/courses/quantum-computing/), and I've reached the lesson on [Quantum Teleportation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/quantum-teleportation/). After completing the lesson and reading several questions and answers here:

1. [quantum teleportation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/322850/quantum-teleportation),
2. [Is quantum teleportation really teleportation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378937/is-quantum-teleportation-really-teleportation),

I'm still struggling to understand its purpose.

If I understand the idea correctly, Quantum State Teleportation works in the following way:

> A qubit represents infinite information because it can be
> in infinite states. Because of this, it's impossible to communicate a
> qubit state in a purely classical way.
>
> However, a state can be "teleported" by entangling two qubits, A and
> B, and giving one to Alice and one to Bob. Then Alice can entangle a
> further qubit, C, with A via a Bell State measurement and send the
> results to Bob classically.
>
> That allows Bob to apply his own measurement that recreates the state Alice's qubit C was originally in before the Bell State measurement.

Apparently, the reason to do this is to avoid thermal decoherence. That makes sense, but surely the entangled qubits A and B are just as susceptible to thermal decoherence?

If that's the case why not send C directly?

Comment: "why not send C directly?" - it's like saying why would you 3D print anything. Suppose a colonist on Mars is in need of a new tool that someone on Earth just designed. You can beam some data, and they can 3D print it there, or you can send cargo on a rocket. One of those is cheaper.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Okay, but if I'm only sending a single qubit in either situation, what's the difference? Can you explain an application to me? I don't understand why it would be useful! How fast is the quantum channel the original entangled qubit went along? Why would I need to teleport state? Your analogy is okay, but you can produce a tool with an extremely small amount of information. It seems the qubit example requires you to send a "tool" anyway, so why not send the original tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scenario is that the qubit C is of superconductor type, which is not good for transmitting long distance, and qubit B is of photon type and is good for long distance transmission. Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

One possible use is to separate sending a qubit from sending information.

For example, suppose you were building a quantum computer with multiple nodes. You could populate the nodes with entangled qubits *before* run-time. That way, when it becomes necessary to transmit quantum information during run-time you could simply send classical bits.